# Factory pattern versus Immutability

Tags: design-patterns, immutability, factory-pattern

I wanted to create a factory for a product. 
However, in order to have the factory class have access to the product class, I would have had to give the setters in the product class package access.

So, instead I decided to give a public static create method directly on the product so that the created product does not get mutated later.

For simple classes, I am inclined to adopt this approach and I want to use the factory pattern only when the product class has quite some reasonable functionality that I want to separate the functionality from the creation.

Am I missing something by preferring the immutability approach?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you provide a better explanation and also some (pseudo-)code that describes what you want to achieve please ?

Comment: Rather than "a public static create method", consider turning that method into a constructor. This will force any construction of that object to supply the values at construction time. If you don't do that then there is a period of time between the object construction and the calling of the method; during which the object doesn't have values, and then they are set. I would not describe that as immutable.